# How can I get the authenticated user's details in a Spring Security on an anonymous page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, cas

I have a large Spring 3.2-based app that uses Spring Security with a CAS authentication strategy. Most of the pages that I have don't have any authentication requirements, however, if a user has logged in, I'd like to display their user name and a link to their page in the menu bar.

This appears to be a problem - Spring Security has a concept of "authenticated pages" where I can call

```
Authentication authentication =
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
CustomUser custom = (CustomUser) authentication == null ? null : authentication.getPrincipal();
```

I get back the CustomUser object no problem. However, even with a user that has been authenticated and has a session, if I call this code on an anonymous/unauthenticated page, I simply get an Anonymous User back.

Is this even possible in Spring Security? It feels like it should exist but there are no examples that I can find or questions answered on S/O.

Here is part of the configuration, with some small redactions.

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint" >
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/reviews/my" method="GET" access="isAuthenticated() and hasRole('ROLE_USER')"  />

    <!-- editing a review -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/reviews/places/review/*" method="GET" access="permitAll"  />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/reviews/places/review/*" method="POST" access="isAuthenticated() and hasRole('ROLE_USER')"  />
    <!-- editing a comment -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/reviews/review/editcomment" method="GET" access="permitAll"  />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/reviews/review/editcomment" method="POST" access="isAuthenticated() and hasRole('ROLE_USER')"  />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/reviews/unsubscribe" access="permitAll"  />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/reviews/reportReview" access="permitAll"  />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/reviews/**" method="POST" access="isAuthenticated() and hasRole('ROLE_USER')"  />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/reviews/settings"  access="isAuthenticated() and hasRole('ROLE_USER')"  />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/reviews/review/deletecomment" method="POST" access="isAuthenticated() and hasRole('ROLE_USER')"  />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/reviews/user/checkLogin" method="GET" access="isAuthenticated() and hasRole('ROLE_USER')"  />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:custom-filter before="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="requestSingleLogoutFilter" />
    <security:custom-filter before="CAS_FILTER" ref="singleLogoutFilter" />
    <security:custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casAuthenticationFilter"  />
    <security:custom-filter after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" ref="ajaxTimeoutRedirectFilter"  />

    <security:logout logout-success-url="/reviews/" delete-cookies="USERINFO" />

</security:http>


<bean id="ajaxTimeoutRedirectFilter" class="com.company.responder.frontend.filter.AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter">
    <property name="customSessionExpiredErrorCode" value="401"/>
</bean>
<!-- handle single logout requests from CAS -->
<bean id="singleLogoutFilter" class="org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter"/>

<!-- This filter redirects to the CAS Server to signal Single Logout should be performed -->
<!--class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">-->
<!--class="com.company.responder.auth.CookieHandlingLogoutFilter">-->
<bean id="requestSingleLogoutFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">

    <constructor-arg value="${security.cas.logoutUrl}"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>

    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/user/logout"/>
</bean>


<!-- Gateway Authentication Filter Bean -->
<bean id="casGatewayFilter"
      class="org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="casServerLoginUrl" value="${security.cas.loginUrl}"/>
    <property name="gateway" value="true"/>
    <property name="renew" value="false"/>
    <property name="serverName" value="${security.cas.clientUrl}"/>
</bean>




<bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
    <property name="service" value="${security.cas.serviceUrl}" />
    <property name="sendRenew" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="casAuthenticationFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <property name="redirectStrategy" ref="redirectStrategy"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="redirectStrategy" class="com.company.responder.auth.RegistrationAwareRedirectStrategy">
    <property name="flashMapManager" ref="flashMapManager"/>
</bean>


<bean name="flashMapManager" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager"/>

<bean id="casEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginUrl" value="${security.cas.loginUrl}" />
    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />

</bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="casAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>



<bean id="casAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="authenticationUserDetailsService" ref="authenticationUserDetailsService"/>


    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
    <property name="ticketValidator">
        <bean id="cas20TicketValidator" class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="${security.cas.baseUrl}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="key" value="CompanyCasAuthenticationProvider" />
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationUserDetailsService" class="com.company.responder.auth.ResponderUserDetailsService"/>
```

Comment: Could you post your security configuration?

Comment: I've added the configuration we're using. We need to be able to access user information on all URLs, not just the ones that we have intercepts for

Answer (score 0):

When making such a kind of things i usually control wether the visitor is logged or not in the jsp view using security taglib this way:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
    <html>

    <div>Starting authorized block --------------------</div>
        <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
            <b>Username:<sec:authentication property="principal.username" /></b>
            <br/>
<b>User profile:</b> <a href="/profiles/<sec:authentication property="principal.username" />">Profile</a>
<br/>
            <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_XXXX')">
            <i>This content will only be visible to users who have
            the requested "ROLE_XXXX" authority in their list of <tt>GrantedAuthority</tt>s.</i>
            </sec:authorize>
            <br/>
        </sec:authorize>
        <div>end of authorized block --------------------</div>


        <div>Starting anonymous block --------------------</div>
        <sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
            <b>The user is anonymous</b>
        </sec:authorize>
        <div>end of anonymous block --------------------</div>
...
```

Comment: The issue is that the user is coming back as anonymousUser even when they are actually logged in

Comment: So, you meant that once logged user is reported as anonymousUser on non secured pages and as authenticated on secured pages? Or as anonymous user on both secured and non-secured pages?

Comment: anonymousUser on non-secured pages and authenticated on secured pages